# Dotted table borders abutting and overlapping in IE6/7

Tags: html, css

I have some `<td>` elements with dotted 1px borders on the bottom. Each element is fixed width. This means that sometimes the borders end up like this, with abutting dots that make a dark spot in the border:

```
-- -- -- --|-- -- -- --
```

but other times they render correctly, like this:

```
-- -- -- --| -- -- --
```

I can move them around by changing the width of the `<td>`s a bit, and sometimes they disappear altogether, but is there a more correct way of rendering fixed-width `<td>`s that would avoid this problem and save me the hassle this has caused?

**EDIT:** `Border-collapse` is applied to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would be in the IE renderer. I don't think there's a standardized (or even IE-specific) way of telling the renderer "start your border rendering with this offset" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You could play with CSS background-images to create the dotted border.  If you created a 2px wide image with a dot as the first pixel and blank as the second, you could then prevent this by making sure all your `<td>` widths were a multiple of 2.